# Write SQL-like queries for java streams

Tags: java, sql, java-stream, in-memory-database

I have a stream of java objects and I would like to query them using SQL-like syntax at a reasonable performance (comparable to querying a regular table without any indexes in an RDBMS, like a one-time full table scan).

I like the Stream API map/filter/etc., but the query would also be an input, so I can't hard-code it in java.

Is it possible to do this without inserting the incoming data into a "real" database (and then removing them later to save space)?
I was thinking about using an in-memory database like H2 or SQLite, but then I would still have to insert the data, and they really are not for streaming.

Are there any existing libraries/solutions for something like I'm trying to do?

```
class A {
    private String name;

    /* ... */
}
```

```
Stream<A> myStream /* = ... */ ;

Stream<Integer> result = query(myStream, "select count(*) as number_of_x from :myStream where name = 'x'",
    (rs, i) -> rs.getInt("number_of_x"));

/* result.toList() will contain one element at the end */
```

Comment: There is no library that I am aware of. However, H2 is written in java, and open source. Thus, it is possible to take specifically their SQL parser. There's plenty about SQL syntax that doesn't really apply to streams, and plenty you might want to add, but if you want it to be SQL based, step 1 is to parse SQL (which is quite a convoluted language). That's where H2's source comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a stream of java objects and I would like to query them

What you want is doesn't make a lot of sense.

Streams are **iterators**, not *containers of data*. See the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> No storage. A **stream is not a data structure** that stores elements; instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline of computational operations.

So the stream aren't a mean of storing data.

And once the stream is consumed, it can't be used anymore. You can query a stream like a database.

A stream is an internal iterator that can be executed only once.

## Update

If you're interested in implementing a Parser for translating SQL-like queries into Predicates and Functions, which would be applied on a stream, then sure you can try. For very simple queries, it's definitely doable.

But it's not a trivial task. A fully-fledged parser for handling simple queries (similar to the one that has been specified in the question) would require a lot of effort both to implement and to test. I doubt whether it would pay off.

Here's a **very, very dumb** illustration which makes use of the Reflection API and regular expressions.

The Demo-parser below is not capable of doing much, the proper implementation would be far more complex.

```
public class QueryParser {
    
    public static <T> long getAsCount(String query, Stream<T> stream, Class<T> tClass) { // overloaded versions for primitive streams
        
        StreamOperation<T> operation = StreamOperation.fromQuery(query, tClass);
        
        return stream
            .filter(operation.getPredicate())
            .count();
    }

    private static class StreamOperation<T> {
        
        public static final Pattern WHERE = Pattern.compile("(?<=(?i)where).*?(?=(?i)group)|(?<=(?i)where).*?(?=$)");
        
        private Predicate<T> predicate;
        // more properties, constructor
        
        public static <T> StreamOperation<T> fromQuery(String query, Class<T> tClass) {
            
            Predicate<T> where = WHERE.matcher(query).results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .findFirst()
                .map(conditions -> parseConditions(conditions, tClass))
                .orElse(t -> true);
            
            // working on other properties
            
            StreamOperation<T> so = new StreamOperation<>(where);
            
            return so;
        }
        
        public Predicate<T> getPredicate() {
            return predicate;
        }
        
        public static <T> Predicate<T> parseConditions(String conditions, Class<T> tClass) {
            
            String[] or = conditions.split("(?i)or"); // split by OR
            
            Predicate<T> orPredicate = t -> false; // base predicate for OR
            
            for (String jointCondition: or) {
                String[] and = jointCondition.split("(?i)and"); // split by END
                
                Predicate<T> andPredicate = t -> true; // base predicate for AND
                
                for (String condition: and) {
                    Predicate<T> next = null;
                    // parse each condition
                    try {
                        next = Conditions.parseCondition(condition, tClass);
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid condition or type:\n"
                            + condition + " for Type " + tClass.getCanonicalName());
                    }
                    andPredicate = andPredicate.and(next); // join conditions together using Predicate.end()
                }
                orPredicate = orPredicate.or(andPredicate); // join conditions together using Predicate.or()
            }
            
            return orPredicate;
        }
    }
    
    private static class Conditions {
        
        public static <T> Predicate<T> parseCondition(String conditions, Class<T> tClass) throws NoSuchFieldException {
            
            // TO DO add logic for other conditions
            // Logic equality comparison implemented for demo purposes
            
            String[] equals = conditions.split("=");
            
            Field field = tClass.getDeclaredField(equals[0].strip());
            field.setAccessible(true);
            
            return field.getType().isPrimitive() ? // assumption that boolean is also represented as numeric value 0 or 1
                compareAsNumericType(field, equals) : compareAsString(field, equals);
            
        }
        
        public static <T> Predicate<T> compareAsNumericType(Field field, String[] equals) {
    
            return t -> {
                try {
                    return field.getDouble(t) == Double.parseDouble(equals[1].strip());
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }
    
        public static <T> Predicate<T> compareAsString(Field field, String[] equals) {
        
            return t -> {
                try {
                    return field.get(t).equals(equals[1].strip().replace("'", ""));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }
    }
    
    // TODO implement methods for retrieving other results

//    public static <T, R> List<R> getAsList(String query, Stream<T> stream, Class<T> tClass) { // overloaded versions for primitive streams
//
//        StreamOperation<T> operation = StreamOperation.fromQuery(query, tClass);
//
//        return stream
//            .filter(operation.getPredicate())
//            .map(operation.getMapper()) // not implemented
//            .toList();
//    }
}
```

A dummy class for testing:

```
public class A {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters, constructor
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String query = "SELECT count(*) as number_of_x from :myStream WHERE name = 'Alise' AND id = 100";
    
    Stream<A> stream = Stream.of(
        new A(100, "Alise"),
        new A(90, "Bob"),
        new A(100, "Carol")
    );
    
    System.out.println(QueryParser.getAsCount(query, stream, A.class));
}
```

*Output:*

```
1
```

Comment: I'd like to query the stream once, like a ksqlDB, but for java streams. You are right that only a small subset of SQL syntax makes sense for streams. Mainly I'd like to filter + group/count.

Comment: @user Then you might try to implement our own query-parser that would translate a query into a bunch of Predicates and Functions, which would be applied on a stream. But it's not a trivial task.

Comment: @user I've added a very basic example of such Parser, it's capable of handling simple queries like the one you've posted. It just a dummy example illustrating, that what I've said is doable, developing a fully-fledged parser even with modest capacities that you need would require a lot of effort.